# calling the same options object on $scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, object

I have the same options object on $scope and I want to use it more than once. How do I differentiate between objects with the same name? This happens to be in angular.

```
$scope.options = {
            chart: {
                type: 'Chart1',
                height: 450,
                width:600
            }
        };
 $scope.options = {
            chart: {
                type: 'Chart2',
                height: 400,
                width:100
            }
        };
```

HTML

```
 <myOptions=**"options"**></myOptions>
```

I am thinking maybe I could to assign them to a variable for starters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no reason to use the same $scope.name for options. I would suggest you to use $scope.optionsOne and $scope.optionsTwo. Otherwise, the second $scope.options overrides the first $scope.options and you're left with only:

$scope.options = {
            chart: {
                type: 'Chart2',
                height: 400,
                width:100
            }
        };

Good luck!

Comment: Yes that is exactly the problem sorry I wasn't clearer.

Comment: Good, so put that green V next to the answer so other users viewing this post will read the correct answer :)

Answer (score 2):

As per my knowledge, the second "options" object will override the first one. It would be better to use constructor function rather than object literal. Declare function and initialize value using parameters. For instance:

```
 $scope.options = {
            myChart: function(param1,param2,param3) {
                type = param1;
                height = param2;
                width = param3;
            }
        };

$scope.options.myChart(val1,val2,val3);
```

There could be better solutions. Please, someone correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: This is the format I was thinking would work- and maybe it still will. I wonder if my fomatting is correct? Do I show that it is a string or number in the last line?         $scope.options = {
            chart:{  function( param1,param2,param3,param4,param5){
                type = param1,
                height = param2,
                width = param3,
                color = param4,
                duration = param5            
            }
        };

Answer (score 0):

Although I'm not sure of the context (one object should overwrite the other), if you are saving the objects in variables, then you can use the strict comparison operator:

```
var opt1 = $scope.options;

//after a possible change in value
if( opt1 === $scope.options ) doStuff(opt1); //note strict comparison
else doStuff( $scope.options )
```

Otherwise, if you know the [type] key you're looking for you can check that:

```
if( $scope.options[type] == 'chart1' ) doStuff( $scope.options );
```

Comment: This seems like it would work, I do know the key. Did I format this correctly? I wasn't sure what to put where you have "doStuff" since all I wan to do is pass in the options   if( $scope.options[type] == 'sunburstChart' )
        $scope.options = {
            chart: {
                height: 450,
                width:600,
                color: d3.scale.category20c(),
                duration: 250
            }
        };